# Remove password attempt at sudo 12.10

Tags: password, sudo, 12.10

I just installed Quantal Quetzal and when I type sudo in the terminal it asks for the password. Before upgrading, I changed something in the file, and it wouldn’t ask for passwords. I have already tried advice from many websites, but none of them worked. Does 12.10 differ with sudo in any way? If anyone can tell me which file to change to fix this, that will be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your main user is member of group 'sudo'. Default settings is to ask your password in order to perform any activity which requires some privilegies.

in order to change it, you need to run in a terminal:

`sudo visudo`

and change this line:

```
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

for this line:

```
%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

save the changes and close your session to have your system taking the changes.

Comment: Do you know how to remove the attempt in the Software Centre?

Comment: @NickyBailuc That's PolicyKit; that's different.